# Ghostscript not working with inkscape on mac

Tags: ghostscript, inkscape

I'm trying to open an .eps file in inkscape. I installed ghostscript and added the bin and lib folders as environment variables but it still won't open. Did I not add them correctly or is there something else I need to do? [photo of my terminal after running env](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9bsD.png)

Edit: Also tried adding them directly to the path variable, which shows up as:

PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/ghostscript/9.55.0/bin:/usr/local/Cellar/ghostscript/9.55.0/lib:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

Many thanks!